# Bits needed to represent image-to-category mapping

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, byte, bit

*You want to map every possible image of size 64 x 64 to a binary category (cat or non-cat). Each image has 3 channels and each pixel in each channel can take an integer value between (and including) 0 and 255.*
Source: http://cs230.stanford.edu/files/cs230exam_win18.pdf

I would have assumed that each pixel value takes 8 bit times 64^2 pixels for each image times 3 for each channel PLUS 1 for the respective category in total: 8*64^2*3+1.

However, the correct solution is 256^{3×64×64}. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think most people missed the first line of the question:

"You want to map **every possible image** of size 64 x 64 to a binary category (cat or non-cat)"

If the question asked how many bits are needed to map **one** image, then your answer is correct: 256 * 64 * 64 * 3

However, the question asked the amount bits needed to map **all possible combinations**, so the correct answer should be: 256 ^ (64 * 64 * 3)

Answer (score 0):

With `64x64` image and `3` channel you have `64x64x3` total units that you need to fill.
For first unit you can fill it with `256` values (`0` to `255`)
For second unit you can fill it with `256` values
So you can fill first two units in `256x256=256^2` ways since you can choose any combination of the integers.
Similarly you can fill first three units in `256x56x256=256^3` ways.
Thus you can fill all the units i.e., the entire image in `256^(64x64x3)` ways since you have 256 option to choose from for each of `64x64x3` units.